# Biber stops with no warning

Tags: biber

After update, biber (version 2.1 now) stopped without giving anything after the "INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8". The same file was compiling before.

System is Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Welcome to SE. I would suggest you to reformulate your question and add your own answer below.

Comment: After splitting my bib file, I discovered this behaviour was caused by the entry (this is copy-paste from Zentralblatt output)   

Abstract = {{Der Verf. ... $$\aligned \format \r \quad &amp;\r\  (x&gt;0) &amp;(1\leqq u\leqq U) \endaligned$$}},   

The culprit is the "\r " which you can just change to "\r\ ".   

This sounds like an unwanted behaviour (the content should not be processed).
This message is for the record, maybe to get reasons why, but also to help others in a similar mess :)  

HTH! I'm happy to be in the clear :)  
Best, A., Olivier

Comment: Good job, but your answer should be written below (see 'Your Answer', 'Post Your Answer').

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is caused by a malformed entry in the bib file

Answer (score 0):

After splitting my bib file, I discovered this behaviour was caused by the entry (this is copy-paste from Zentralblatt output)

```
Abstract = {{Der Verf. ... $$\aligned \format \r \quad &amp;\r\ (x&gt;0) &amp;(1\leqq u\leqq U) \endaligned$$}},
```

The culprit is the `\r` which you can just change to `\r\`. This sounds like an unwanted behaviour (the content should not be processed). This message is for the record, maybe to get reasons why, but also to help others in a similar mess :)

HTH! I'm happy to be in the clear :)

Best, A., Olivier